# Append Data To NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My app is of type SplitView and I am using `UITableView` to display the name of sites. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I am using the following the lines of code ::

```
dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: urlString, dateString, nil];

[history addObject:dict];

NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString); //will let you know if it's nil or not
NSLog(@"urlString : %@", [dict objectForKey:dateString]);

NSString *docDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSLog(@"docDir is yoyo :: %@", docDir);
NSString *spaceFilePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"space.txt"];
[history writeToFile:spaceFilePath atomically: TRUE];
```

I am trying to add the url of sites visited alongwith the timestamp into the `NSDictionary` "dict". I have initialised formatter in `viewDidLoad` method.  History is an array which stores the list of dictionaries.

I have used the following lines of code in `viewDidLoad` method :

```
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

I want to append the name of the new site visited into the already existing file space.txt.

But, however, only one name appears (the last visited site's url). How can I append the newly visited siteNames into my already existing file space.txt? I am unable to sort out this issue.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: After adding dict, print history and verify the values?and as @Rajesh suggested check whether your history is nil or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your code also. Please cross check that have you allocated the "history" object in viewDidLoad or not. If not, please make it.

Comment: well yes .. lol .. allocating the history object in viewDidLoad worked too !! thanks a lot !! this 1 single line did the job ::  "history = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];"

Comment: but can you also tell me some reasoning for the allocation of this memory ?? I am getting confused with the statement of AliSoftware below.

Comment: If you are not allocating memory for an object and you are adding some value to that, means processor is going to save the data temporary memory and whenever the scope is completed it will remove the temporary data. So that you can not able to use this details out of the scope with out allocating. In your case every time the data which you are appending is saving into temporary memory and after the scope it is removing the added data. So that every time it is saving only preset assigned data.

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSMutableDictionary (and not an NSDictionary) to have a dictionary that is mutable (= that can be modified).

---

*Addendum*:
Note that your line `dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];` is totally useless, as you reaffect the variable "dict" in the very next line. That's quite like if you did sthg like: `int a = 5;` followed by `a=8`, of course the value that was in the variable before is replaced by the new one, and the previous value (your `[[NSDictionary alloc] init]` in your cas) is lost.

Comment: kz .. I tried using NSMutableDictionary too and removed the line pointed by you. The code is still not working i.e. still only the last visited site is being written to the file space.txt :-/

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the object ("dict") is different for every time. Means simply you are adding the selected details in the dictionary and writing that. So you are not able to see the previous saved details. Check the following code for append the newly visited siteNames into my already existing file space.txt.

```
dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *docDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *spaceFilePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"space.txt"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:spaceFilePath]) {
    NSMutableDictionary *appendDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:spaceFilePath];
    [appendDict setObject:urlString forKey:dateString];
    [appendDict writeToFile:spaceFilePath atomically: TRUE];  
    [appendDict release];
} else {
    NSMutableDictionary *appendDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:urlString, dateString, nil];
    [appendDict writeToFile:spaceFilePath atomically: TRUE];  
    [appendDict release];
}
```

I think this can be useful.